# Why is an extra character ("X") added to the rownames of my data.frame?

Tags: r

Originally the `rownames` of my data (a `csv`-file) were:

```
1
5
33
37
```

However, as I read in my data using:

```
data <- read.table(data, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

it seems that the `rownames` has been transformed to:

```
X1
X5
X33
X37
```

Are there any common reasons for why this is happening? It's entirely unintentional.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441437/x-in-my-column-names-of-an-r-data-frame) may help.

Comment: make the question reproducible please

Comment: as I said in a comment on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177756/deleting-an-extra-character-in-each-row?noredirect=1#comment34854740_22177756), you could see values in a data frame that had `X` prepended if you did some sort of melting/casting where what were previously numeric values turned into **column** names and were then re-converted into data values.  However, I agree with Greg Snow's answer below that you have to be doing something special in order for **row** names to be mutated in this way.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that it is the row names that are changing? not the column names?

R generally does not modify row names, it is happy with numbers (converted to character) as row names.

The standard functions for reading in data (`read.table` and relatives) will convert column names that are not valid names into ones that are, for integers this mean prepending the `X` that you describe.  If you don't want this behavior (skipping this helpful feature could lead to other complications down the line) then look at the `check.names` argument to `read.table`.

If it really is the row names that are changing then we will need a reproducible example with a text file to read in and the exact command that you used to read in the file.